# Не все изменения в php.ini работают

Tags: apache, php.ini, php, linux

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: изменяю настройки в php.ini, но изменяются не все, к примеру, параметр `max_execution_time` изменяется, а `error_reporting` и `display_errors` - не меняются.

Debian, apache 5.5.4

Думал, проблема в том, что редактирую не тот файл настроек, но ведь некоторые параметры меняются. Прошу подсказать, как решить данный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Проблему решил. Новые версии PHP не разрешают изменение глобальных настроек, поэтому нужно в папке доп. ini файлов (у меня это `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`) создать файл user.ini и уже в нём прописать нужные настройки.